# When I click on item in recyclerview, how can I retrieve data from firebase and show it in a list view in the next activity?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

This is my recyclerview class where I have electrician, plumber, welder etc as my recyclerview items. I want whenever user click on any of these items the respective data that is retrieved from firebase should be shown in the next activity.

```
package com.example.hp.dc_project;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

/** * Created by HP on 20-07-2018. */
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<category> mdata;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<category> mdata) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mdata = mdata;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_category,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tv.setText(mdata.get(position).getName());
        holder.iv.setImageResource(mdata.get(position).getThumnail());
        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(mContext.getApplicationContext(),available_worker.class);
                mContext.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mdata.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tv;
        ImageView iv;
        CardView cardView;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tv = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_category);
            iv = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_category);
            cardView = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the activity class where I want to display the listview containing the data that is retrieved from firebase after clicking on the recyclerview items:

```
package com.example.hp.dc_project;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class available_worker extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView lv;
    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private ArrayList<String>list;
    private ArrayAdapter<String>adapter;
    private Electrician elec;
    //  adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Electrician>(this,R.layout.list_of_work    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_available_worker);
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_workeravailable);
        elec = new Electrician();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(available_worker.this,WorkerProfile.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_of_worker,R.id.employeeadd);
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference rootref = database.getReference();
        DatabaseReference electricianref = rootref.child("Employee").child("Electrician");
        electricianref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String fName = ds.child("Fname").getValue(String.class);
                    String lName = ds.child("Lname").getValue(String.class);
                    String address = ds.child("Address").getValue(String.class);
                    list.add(fName);
                    list.add(lName);
                    list.add(address);
                }
             }

             @Override
             public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
             }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I've edited your question to fix some typos and format your code. Please make sure your code is formatted next time. Nobody wants to dig through lots of messy code. Make it easy for people to help you. That said, please [edit] your question and state how your code is not working as expected. Do you get any errors? If so, include them in your question (with any stack traces). What is happening when you run your code? What do you expect to happen instead? See also [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

In on click get your worker id and put in extra , in the next activity put value event listner and get the respective data but you have one thing is that you have to have the id  or something which can uniquely identify the reference of firebase.

```
holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(mContext.getApplicationContext(),available_worker.class);
                    i.putExtra("uid",workerid);
                    mContext.startActivity(i);
                }
            });
```

in the next activity

```
String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("uid");
firebaseref.child(s).addvalueEventListner(////) {//pupulate your list view}
```

Comment: And where to add the database retrieve code ??in the secnd activity where there is a listview or in the first activity where i have the recyclerview adapter so that when i click on any item in recyclerview the retrieve function gets called and show the data in listview in nxt activity

Comment: In the first activity find the id of worker when you are adding recycler view then send this id to anther activity then find all the data from firebase in next activuty

Comment: But in order to find the id again i have to connect it to the database for retrieving the id

Comment: Bcoz id is created from a webpage where worker enter all the details..so how can i retrieve that id which is generated from a webpage into my recyclerview adapter..